# Titanium index.html

Tags: android, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

ive just installed titanium and the android sdk for development. In my project i have an index.html but its not loading that when i do a build, it keeps loading a 'welcome to titanium' html page which for the life of me i just can't find anywhere to see where its being loaded from.

How the heck do i set *my* index.html to be the one that is loaded when the app first loads? I have tried adding

index2.html (index2 as a test) but its still loading this welcome to titanium url even when i make a new blank project.

Comment: What is inside app.js?

Comment: Do a "Search" in the project for "welcome to titanium" and that will show the file that is loading.

Comment: what documentation are you looking at? index.html?? that is now how apps are built using Appcelerator Titanium

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you created a default alloy project, all the `app/controllers/index.xml` file does is load another controller, probably called FirstView or something like that. Look through your `views` directory inside the `app` directory for another `.xml` file.

The structure of Alloy is that the `index.xml` file is loaded first no matter what, so it is not even recognizing your `index2.xml`. I would highly recommend you go through the [Alloy Quick Start](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Quick_Start) to get the general concepts first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are working with titanium alloy.

if so, your file should be index.xml and not index.html

index.xml contains  as a child node of  node.

for allow project you can find index.xml file and for the same file there is a controller file in folder app/controller/index.js.

in index.js file there must b a following line

```
index.open()
```

this line will open the index.xml file in your app.

**Note :**  if you have given id attribute to window node in xml than you should use $..open(). this should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

It should be `index.xml` and body should be like this:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="xyz">
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Then there should be `index.js` file where you have to call this xml file by id:

```
$.xyz.open();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and don't enclose actual statements in code-formatting