# Titanium File /index.html not found

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium

Im just started the default template  ¨Hello World¨ Project, Its a fresh installation and I didn't make any changes, but everytime a try to run the project, I get the **File /index.html not found** error...

PLease help!! Thanks for your attention! :D

Answer (score 0):

This Question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911356/titanium-index-html) by [Josiah Hester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874257/josiah-hester)

> Sounds like you created a default alloy project, all the app/controllers/index.xml file does is load another controller, probably called FirstView or something like that. Look through your views directory inside the app directory for another .xml file.
>
> The structure of Alloy is that the index.xml file is loaded first no matter what, so it is not even recognizing your index2.xml. I would highly recommend you go through the Alloy Quick Start to get the general concepts first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, im not using a "index2.xml" or anything like that, actually this happens also with a HTML based project

Comment: I have this on views>index.xml
<Alloy>
 <Window class="container">
  <Label id="label" onClick="doClick">Hello, World</Label>
 </Window>
</Alloy>

THANKS!